# Swagger parameters in query and/or body

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

Our API has such endpoints that support parameters both from the `query` and from the `body` at the same time, by merging those two sets of parameters.

For example:

```
/foo?param1=value1
body: {
    param2=value2
}
```

The resulting set of parameters would contain two, `param1` and `param2`.

This endpoint could be used as:

```
/foo?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

OR

```
/foo
body: {
    param1=value1,
    param2=value2
}
```

Is there a way how to specify this 'duality' in Swagger?

**UPD**
I suppose I should define parameter as both: `body` and `query`

```
in:
  - body
  - query
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to define both query parameters and body parameters but mark all of them as optional. Use the operation `description` to explain that the client can send the parameters in either query string or body.

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
...
paths:
  /foo:
    post:
      consumes:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: param1
          type: string
          required: false
        - in: query
          name: param2
          type: string
          required: false
        - in: body
          name: body
          required: false
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              param1:
                type: string
              param2:
                type: string
```

Using OpenAPI 3.0, it's a bit more elegant in that you can reuse the same `schema` for the query string and the request body:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...
paths:
  /foo:
    post:
      parameters:
        # This expands into ?param1=value1&param2=value2&...
        - in: query
          name: parameters
          required: false
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Parameters'
          style: form
          explode: true
      requestBody:
        required: false
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Parameters'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK

components:
  schemas:
    Parameters:
      type: object
      properties:
        param1:
          type: string
        param2:
          type: string
```

Note for Swagger UI users: Serialization of objects into query string seems to be not supported yet as of UI v. 3.11.0.

Comment: May I group them like suggested at [#445](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/445) issue. Is this available already?

Comment: @EugenKonkov: The [#445](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/445) proposal is still open, so no, it's not possible. You can only `$ref` individual parameters but not groups of parameters.